# Confused about the [documentation] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The description for the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag says

> THIS TAG IS FOR DOCUMENT GENERATORS ONLY. Include language and/or SDE tag as well. DO NOT USE to ask for links to documentation or tools, or to critique vendor documentation

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065579/confusion-about-arm-documentation-on-carry-flag), I was confused about some ARM documentation and what it was saying. I think this would generally fall under the category of "critique[ing] vendor documentation".

Is there an alternate documentation tag I should use for the linked question? Or should I just not put any tags on it related to documentation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Asking about some existing documentation and using the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag would make that tag a [meta tag, thus discouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). This is because the question isn’t really *about* documentation itself, it’s about the *content* of some specific documentation. Tag the content: if the documentation is about [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) and (more importantly) your question is about [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm), tag [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm).

This tag would just tell you the source of some parts of the question, but this is useless as a tag. Likewise, we don’t use [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) or [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) to convey “I want to ask about this thing that I found on *a website / the internet*”.

So, remove [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation); its correct usage doesn’t convey any meta information.

Comment: "Likewise, we don’t use website or internet" oh, but we did.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Just dropped the tag from the question

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be a synonym of [tag:documentation-generation] then?

Comment: @DidierL I would think so. In fact, currently [194 questions are tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation-generation+documentation), which seems completely redundant.

Comment: @DidierL Rather sounds like it should be burninated, since "documentation" is a horrible tag name. If there's another better tag filling the purpose, that one should take over.

Comment: If the tag has to SCREAM at you, clearly it shouldn't exist!